# Trazer a imagens com ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

É o seguinte pessoal, eu consegui armazenar os links das imagens no banco de dados e também armazenei essa imagens em uma pasta do meu computador. então eu queria saber como posso pegar essas imagens com o javascript e joga-las no meu site. Mais ou menos assim eu consultaria essas imagens no banco e obteria o link dela, com esse link eu queria poder jogar na minha página a parti do java script, eu estou obtendo esses links com o *ajax*, apenas não estou sabendo passar a imagem  para o site, a descrição eu consegui, como eu faço isso é possível fazer?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var imageName;
 
   var postagens = function(){
  

  $('#retorno').empty();  

  $.ajax({
   method : 'GET',
   url :'postagens.php',
   dataType : 'json',
   complete: function(dados){

     response = dados.responseJSON;

     for(var i = 0 ; response.length > i; i++){
     //document.getElementById("retorno").innerHTML = response[i].descricao;
     $('#retorno').append('<p>'+ response[i].descricao +'</p> <br>');
     

     }

   } 

  });
}

   

});
```

```html
</div>

            <div>
                    <form id="conteudo" >

                         <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleTextarea"></label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPostar" name="btnPostar" >Postar</button> 
                            <input type="file" name="btnImage" id="btnImage"  class="btnImage" accept="image/*">
                            <hr size="1"> 

                            <p id="retorno"  name="retorno" > </p> <br>
                            <img  id="imagem"  src="">
                            
                    </form>
                
                
              </div>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo, adicione dentro do *for* , `$("#imagem").attr("src", response[i].imagem);`, mais tenho uma dúvida, porque estar a usa o `for` ? É necessário para o que você esta fazendo ? Pois se for apenas retornado um resultado, não é necessário usa-lo.

Comment: Vlw ai cara. e o for tipo para funcionar como postagens!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a mesma ideia que você fez com a descrição.

Vamos supor que seu retorno do banco seja `imagem`, faria assim...

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'SUA URL',
   success: function(data){
      $('#retorno').append('<img src="'+data.imagem+'">');
   }
})
```

Dessa maneira, sempre será criado uma imagem nova com o caminho que está no banco.

Comment: Vlw ai amigo!!!

Comment: @IgorMartins De nada, se resolver seu problema, não esquece de dar +1 e marcar como resolvido.